# iOS 11 - WKWebView progress KVO never reach 100%

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm testing an app for the upcomming release of iOS 11. While navigating with the in-app browser (WKWebView), I use KVO to update progress. Unfortunately, it never reaches 100%. Here's my code (works perfectly in iOS 10):

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
        print("progres \(webView.estimatedProgress)")
        if webView.estimatedProgress == 1.0 {
            print("progress reached 100%")
            progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.3, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.progressView.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: { (finished) in
                self.progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
                self.progressView.isHidden = true
            })
        }
        else {
            progressView.alpha = 1.0
            progressView.isHidden = false
            progressView.setProgress(Float(webView.estimatedProgress), animated: true)
        }
    } else if keyPath == "title" {
        navigationItem.title = webView.title
    }
    else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of what the print output to Xcode console:

```
> progres 0.1 
> progres 0.5 
> progres 0.55430649853092 
> progres 0.771510689002141 
> progres 0.77167516785194
```

Answer (score 0):

After investigations, it looks like the problem comes from complexe network settings for a specific internal URL I'm using. The use of a proxy fixed the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please specify what kind of changes you have done to resolve this.

Comment: The phone I was using was connected to a Wi-Fi network that was going through a proxy which was blocking some of the requests the web page was doing.